# How to calculate value of a percent of a range

Tags: percentages

Hi I have a range and percent of that range. I want to calculate the value of that percentage.

for exam:

```
min = -5
max = 30
percentage = 8%

value = ?
```

Value should be a `8%` of the range of `(-5 .. 30)`

Comment: The question is all but trivial since percentage is a linear function of the value given the range. Have you tried to solve for it?

Comment: I don't know math and yes I tried !

Comment: Calculate the $8\%$ point of the range $[0,35]$ then shift it down by $5$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since$$
\text{percentage} = \frac{\text{value} - \min}{\max - \min} \times 100\%,
$$
then$$
\text{value} = \min + (\max - \min) \times \text{percentage}.
$$

Comment: Thanks, It works :-)

Answer (score 0):

Find $8\%$ of $30-(-5)$. That is $$\frac{8}{100}\times 35=m.$$ Then what you want is $-5+m$.